# How to use QgsCoordinateTransformContext to export vector layer to another CRS?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis, export

I am having troubles to export a vector layer to another Coordinate Reference System (CRS) using `WriteAsVectorFormatV2` and `QgsCoordinateTransformContext`.
I looked in many posts related to `QgsCoordinateTransformContext` but did not find any example on how to use it for my needs.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
##########
# Test 1 #
########## 
# This is a vector layer of point geometry and CRS set to EPSG:4326
input = iface.activeLayer()

context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
ref_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4258")
# According to the documentation, if the third element is void, it should use the default PROJ conversion string 
context.addCoordinateOperation(ref_crs, dest_crs, "")

s_out = r"test_out_1.gpkg"
o_save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
o_save_options.layerName = lyr_airports.name()
tpl_err = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(lyr_airports, s_out, context, o_save_options)
# The layer is written and I can load it in QGIS but it does not have information about CRS

##########
# Test 2 #
########## 
# This is a vector layer of point geometry and CRS set to EPSG:4326
input = iface.activeLayer()

context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
ref_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4258")
# I obtained the PROJ string with the following command: projinfo -o PROJ -s EPSG:4326 -t EPSG:4258
context.addCoordinateOperation(ref_crs, dest_crs, "+proj=noop")

s_out = r"test_out_2.gpkg"
o_save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
o_save_options.layerName = lyr_airports.name()
tpl_err = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(lyr_airports, s_out, context, o_save_options)
# The layer is written and I can load it in QGIS but it does not have information about CRS
```

In both test cases, I get the output layer and I can load it back in QGIS, where it is displayed without any information about the CRS.

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 2-3 hour of testing and trying, I solve my problem and your question!
I add the following lines:

```
.....

coordinateTransformContext=QgsProject.instance().transformContext()

o_save_options.ct = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem( 'EPSG:4326') ,QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3844'),coordinateTransformContext)

.....
```

My problems was that the exported layers remain in the same CRS EPSG:4326. I make a `dir(save_options)` and saw the `ct` member. I try to set `o_save_options` and find the solutions.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the nice solution. It works fine. Cheers